# PyQt 4 UI freezes

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

The following programm should just count up and int and displays its value in a label.
But after a while the GUI stops working, while the loop continous.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore
import sys

class main_window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        #Layout       
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.bt=QtGui.QPushButton('crash')
        self.lbl=QtGui.QLabel('count')
        ver=QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        ver.addWidget(self.bt)
        ver.addWidget(self.lbl)
        self.cnt=0
        self.running=False
        self.connect(self.bt,QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.count)

    def count(self):
        self.running=True
        while self.running:
            self.cnt+=1
            print self.cnt
            self.lbl.setText(str(self.cnt))
            self.repaint()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw=main_window()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def count(self):
    self.running=True
    while self.running:
        self.cnt+=1
        print self.cnt
        self.lbl.setText(str(self.cnt))
        self.repaint()
```

Have you thought about any exit from this endless loop? E.g. `self.running=False`.
GUI may stop working because it doesn't have enough time to perform `repaint`. You may want to add some `time.sleep` in the loop to wait for the GUI to repaint.

**Upd.:** You should use [QTimer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtimer.html), not a simple while loop, for the behavior you're implementing.

Comment: I tried to simplify my problem as much as possible, so yes, a stop button is planed.
Putting in a time sleep command even crashs the gui faster.

Comment: You'd better be using QTimer(http://doc.trolltech.com/3.3/qtimer.html) instead of while loop and start/stop it as desired.

Comment: Besides, your stop button won't work so long as the while loop is being executed if you are using single thread. So, as I've mentioned, try using QTimer.

Comment: Ok, got it working with using a QTimer with 0 ms instead. Thaks.

Answer (score 7):

You're not letting Qt's event loop run, so the GUI is not responding. Also, `repaint()` is not needed, the `QLabel.setText()` will repaint the label. All it does is queue up an extra paint event, but this never gets processed.

What you need to do is replace `self.repaint()` with **`QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()`**. This will give the app a chance to process any pending events (including that repaint, as well as ui interaction) while you're in the loop.

Comment: `QtGui.QGuiApplication.processEvents()` in pyQt5

Answer (score 2):

You have to let the main event loop run, something you're not doing.

Comment: Sorry, i am quite new to pyqt, but dosent paint invoke the main loop?