# Change Case to Capital on focusOutEvent

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside, qlineedit

I have a customized QLineEdit editor for inputting initials in a delegated QTableWidget. I would like to force upper case once the focus has been left **without** using an input mask (f.i. without using self.setInputMask(">AA"))

Notes:
- the QLineEdit text **does** get changed to uppercase when called
- the new uppercase text **does not** get reflected in the QLineEdit when focus is lost

See the custom class below:

```
class InitialsEditor(QLineEdit):
    # The custom editor for editing the Initials

    # a signal to tell the delegate when we have finished editing
    editingFinished = Signal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
            # Initialize the editor object
            super(InitialsEditor, self).__init__(parent)
            self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
            rx = QRegExp("[A-Z]{1,2}") # validate A-Z with 2 characters
            rx.setCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
            self.setValidator(QRegExpValidator(rx, self)) # limit the input to A-Z
            #self.setMaxLength(2) # limit the max char length
            #self.setInputMask(">AA")

    def focusOutEvent(self, event):
            # Once focus is lost, tell the delegate we're done editing
            self.setText(self.text().upper()) # make the text uppercase
            print(self.text()) # returns the correct self.text() in uppercase...
            self.editingFinished.emit()
```

Comment: You should call the default implementation of `QLineEdit::focusOutEvent` instead of emitting `editingFinished` manually. May be the default implementation does something important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out an alternative solution based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422419/python-pyqt-could-not-display-data-in-lineedit-and-print-command-in-terminal-wi). This solution results in only caps being entered regardless of case sensitive input (f.i. a or A results in A).

The solution involves switching out the editingFinished event with textEdited event and associating it with the following new definition for my Class InitialsEditor:

```
def updatedText(self):
            self.setText(self.text().upper())
            QApplication.instance().processEvents()
```